# Limit of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sigma{(k)}}{k!}$?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, summation

Evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\sigma{(k)}}{k!}= ?$$

where $\sigma(n)$ is defined as $$\sigma{(N)}=\sum_{d|N}d$$

Comment: $\sigma(k)$ is much smaller than $k!$ for large $k$, so the series should converge pretty quickly. A few terms ought to give you as many decimal places as you want. I think it's unlikely there will be a closed form.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a remark, but a bit long for a comment: suppose that the limit is $S$. Since we have $n<\sigma(n)<\frac{n^2}{\phi(n)}<n^2$ for all $n>1$, it follows
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k!}<\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sigma(k)}{k!}<\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{k!},
$$
so that $e\le S\le 2e$ for the limit. The upper bound for $\sigma(k)$ can be improved by $e^{\gamma}k \log \log k$, assuming RH, or just $\sigma(k)<2.59 k\log \log k$ for all $k\ge 7$ unconditionally. This gives a better upper bound for $S$.

 Computing the first terms I obtain $S\sim 3.527000471$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sigma(n)}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(id*1)(n)}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(kn)!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{t=1}^n e^{e^{2\pi i t/n}}-1$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sigma(n)}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{t=1}^n (\large{e^{e^{2\pi i t/n}}}-1)$$

Comment: This is true, but does this get us closer to the limit?